# How to run SOLR on amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, solr, amazon-ec2

I am able to successfully start SOLR on windows by using following command:

> solr-5.2.1/bin/solr.cmd start -p 9393 -s eposro/solr

This doesn't work on amazon linux. I get following errors.

```
@echo: command not found
solr-5.2.1/bin/solr.cmd: line 19: IF: command not found
solr-5.2.1/bin/solr.cmd: line 21: REM: command not found
solr-5.2.1/bin/solr.cmd: line 42: IF: command not found
solr-5.2.1/bin/solr.cmd: line 75: IF: command not found
solr-5.2.1/bin/solr.cmd: line 76: syntax error near unexpected token `('
solr-5.2.1/bin/solr.cmd: line 76: `IF NOT EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" ('
```

Java_HOME has been set as follows:

`echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/`

Is there a different way to run SOLR on amazon linux or am I doing anthing wrong?

Comment: Errors like this happen when a MS Windows batch file is run in a Linux bash shell

Comment: I felt the same. So I asked is there any other way?

Comment: Apparently, I am using a wrong SOLR build that is not suppose to be used on UNIX/LINUX. Your comment made me think in that direction and I think I have found the solution for this. I'll try it out !

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to solr directory & make sure solr home path you are starting with is correct.  enter `bin/solr start -p 9393 -s esposro/solr`  try updating Java version if you dont have latest.

And also check the port number(9393) you using with Amazon EC2 to start solr is enabled with firewall.

Comment: Yes the port is running. I tried to run some other service on port 9393 and it worked. Even tried navigating to SOLR directory and executing that command, but getting same errors. 
I have following java version: `java version "1.8.0_101"`. I think this is the latest

Comment: I feel  $JAVA_HOME is not set properly. try this `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101`

Comment: we have to point to main java jdk folder.  JAVA_HOME should not point java.exe file